# concatenate single character from an array with string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, concatenation

Hey everyone I have one problem. I am trying to concatenate a single value from array with the string but it is not concatenating.

Example

```
arr[] => ['R','b','c']
string => "am"
```

I want to arr[0] + string i.e.., concatenate first index value of array to string.

How can I do this without changing the data type of array or string just concatenate array to string.

Edit: Here is the code

```js
function rotate() {
  var string = document.getElementById("string").value

  var str_arr = string.split();

  document.getElementById("string").value = str_arr[string.length - 1] + string.substring(0, string.length - 1);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <label for="name">String:</label>
  <input type="text" id="string" name="string">
</fieldset>
<button type="submit" onclick="rotate()">Rotate</button>
```

Comment: May you edit the question with the javascript where you are concatenating? --- Also how can you concatenate `['R','b','c']` to `'am'`??

Comment: If i understand correct 'I am trying to concatenate a single value from array with the string ' you should do sometjing like

arr[0] + 'am' => 'Ram'

Comment: `string = arr[0] + string;` ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Please check the updated code.

Comment: Don't get it. You just want a string on input to duplicate at beginning the first character?

Comment: @JurijJazdanov I am trying to rotate a string at each button click.

Comment: @phpNoob check answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse a string split it into array, rotate array and join it back to a string.

```js
function check(){
  var string = document.getElementById("string").value;
  document.getElementById("string").value = string.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
      <label for="name">String:</label>
      <input type="text" id="string" name="string">
</fieldset>
<button type="submit" onclick="check()">Rotate</button>
```

To move last character in beginning of a string use substrings:

```js
function check(){
  var string = document.getElementById("string").value;
  
  document.getElementById("string").value = string.substr(string.length - 1) + string.substr(0, string.length - 1);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
      <label for="name">String:</label>
      <input type="text" id="string" name="string">
</fieldset>
<button type="submit" onclick="check()">Rotate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using charAt() function.

function rotate(){

var string = document.getElementById("string").value
  var str_arr = string.split();
  document.getElementById("string").value = string.charAt(string.length - 1) + string.substring(0, string.length - 1);

}